# Check multiple regex patterns

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am working on a calculator for feet and inch calculations. I currently have a program that works but so far I can only get it to work if you input the full measurement (ie 4'-0" instead of just 4' or 0'-6" instead of just 6"). I would like to be able to have it check against a few patterns as to be able to input just feet, inches, fractions of an inch, or a combination of the above.

I have tried making one variable with all the different patterns in it but I must be missing something to be able to parse through the variable to find the correct pattern (this attempted is commented out in the code). I found other code using this method and tried to replicate it to work for me but no luck. I have also tried making each pattern its own variable but then I was unsure how to check against each pattern and return whether or not it was a match. Maybe I am over thinking this and its easy but I am stumped.

Sorry for posting a link to the entire code but I figured that it was easier for you to be able to see and use what I am working with instead of just code snippets. Thanks in advance for any help.

Link to the code:

https://repl.it/repls/PrestigiousKeyMemorypool

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's generally more helpful if you narrow down the code to the specific problem and post that question. See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's particularly important with links as they can break.

Comment: What do you expect `regex.search(*args)` to do? Regex only searches for matches in *strings*. You can't run it on a tuple.

Comment: Is the point of the project to practice regex? If you're just practicing regex, then your approach makes sense. But if you're actually trying to make a calculator application, then I believe there are simpler options.

Comment: I am actually trying to build the application but it is also a learning tool as I am learning python. I agree there probably are simpler options to accomplish what I am doing and I am open to other ideas and methods to make my code better and more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using named groups and make each part optional (including the dash):

```
regex = re.compile(r'(?P<feet>[0-9]+\')?\-?(?P<inches>[0-9]+")?')
```

And modify the following functions and you will be set.

```
def ftbreakdown(*args):
  search = regex.search(*args)
  print(search)
  feetsearch = search.group('feet')
  feet = int(feetsearch.split("'")[0]) if feetsearch is not None else 0
  return feet

def inbreakdown(*args):
  search = regex.search(*args)
  print(search)
  if search is None:
    inches = 0
  else:
    inchsearch = search.group('inches')
    inches = int(inchsearch.split('"')[0]) if inchsearch is not None else 0
  # print(inches)
  return inches
```

This is the quick and dirty way, but it works. You can obviously poptimize this further.

***Sample run***

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Enter length: 4'-2"
Choose operation: +
Enter length: 6"
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='4\'-2"'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='6"'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='4\'-2"'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='6"'>
4'-8"
Choose operation:
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That was a simple solution. Just for my knowledge and curiosity what would be the best way to go about searching through multiple patterns.